# Android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6 error inflating class

Tags: android, xml

I'm recieiveing an android.view.inflateException when I load one of my activities. It didn't seem to do this earlier but since I changed the launch activity to a different one which now launches the one that isn't working on the press of a button. It says that there is a indexOutOfBoundsException on the linked list yet I don't see anything I changed (except the contents of the drawable folder). Thanks for any help!

Here is the Logcat:

```
04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start      activity            ComponentInfo{net.semantic.games/net.semantic.games.AndrongActivity}: android.view.InflateException:         Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class net.semantic.games.AndrongSurfaceView
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class net.semantic.games.AndrongSurfaceView
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:214)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.AndrongActivity.onCreate(AndrongActivity.java:24)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     ... 11 more
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     ... 21 more
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at java.util.LinkedList.get(LinkedList.java:520)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.Sprite.getWidth(Sprite.java:84)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.Sprite.centerHorizontal(Sprite.java:208)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.Sprite.center(Sprite.java:202)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.AndrongThread.<init>(AndrongThread.java:53)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.AndrongSurfaceView.CreateNewAndrongThread(AndrongSurfaceView.java:57)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     at net.semantic.games.AndrongSurfaceView <init>(AndrongSurfaceView.java:28)
    04-05 11:03:31.566: E/AndroidRuntime(6112):     ... 24 more
    04-05 11:03:31.578: E/(109): Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Here is the XML File of the activity:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<net.semantic.games.AndrongSurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/androng"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
      android:id="@+id/text"
      android:text="Androng"
      android:visibility="visible"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
      android:gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:textColor="#99FFFFFF"
      android:textSize="16sp"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Android Surface View Class:

```
    package net.semantic.games;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndrongSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
private AndrongThread androngThread;
private TextView statusText;
private SurfaceHolder holder;
private Context context;

public AndrongSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
  super(context, attrs);
  this.context = context;
  this.holder = getHolder();
  holder.addCallback(this);
  setFocusable(true);
  androngThread = CreateNewAndrongThread();
}

public void setTextView(TextView textView)
{
  statusText = textView;
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
{
  androngThread.setRunning(true);
  try
  {
     androngThread.start();
  }
  catch (Exception error)
  {
     androngThread = CreateNewAndrongThread();
     androngThread.start();
     androngThread.setRunning(true);
  }
}

private AndrongThread CreateNewAndrongThread()
{
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Select Menu for a new game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  toast.show();

  return new AndrongThread(holder, context, new Handler()
  {
     @Override
     public void handleMessage(Message m)
     {
        Bundle bundle = m.getData();
        if (bundle.containsKey("viz"))
        {
           statusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
           statusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
        }
        else if (bundle.containsKey("toast"))
        {
           Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, bundle.getString("toast"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           toast.show();
        }
     }
  });
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height)
{
  androngThread.setSurfaceSize(width, height);
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder)
{
  androngThread.setRunning(false);
  boolean retry = true;
  while (retry)
  {
     try
     {
        androngThread.join();
        retry = false;
     }
     catch (InterruptedException e)
     {
     }
  }
}

public AndrongThread getAndroidPongThread()
{
  return androngThread;
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus)
{
   if (!hasWindowFocus)
  {
     androngThread.pause();
  }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
  float xPosition1 = 0;
  float yPosition1 = 0;
  float xPosition2 = 0;
  float yPosition2 = 0;

  for (int pointerIndex = 0; pointerIndex < event.getPointerCount(); pointerIndex++)
  {
     if (pointerIndex == 0)
     {
        xPosition1 = event.getX(pointerIndex);
        yPosition1 = event.getY(pointerIndex);
     }

     if (pointerIndex == 1)
     {
        xPosition2 = event.getX(pointerIndex);
        yPosition2 = event.getX(pointerIndex);
     }
  }

  switch (event.getAction())
  {
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        androngThread.setBattPosition(xPosition1, yPosition1, xPosition2, yPosition2);
        break;
  }
  return true;
}
}
```

DrawableResourceCollection Class:

```
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.util.LinkedList;

public class DrawableResourceCollection extends LinkedList<Drawable>
{
}
```

Sprite Class:
       package net.semantic.games;

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class Sprite
{
protected double xPosition;
protected double yPosition;
protected DrawableResourceCollection drawableResourceCollection;
private Bitmap internalBitmap;
private int canvasWidth;
private int canvasHeight;

protected Velocity velocity;
private int currentFrame = 0;
private double animationSpeedInFpms;
private long startTimeInMillis;
private boolean animationForward;

public Sprite(DrawableResourceCollection drawableResourceCollection, int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight, int animationSpeedInFps, boolean animationForward)
{
  this.canvasWidth = canvasWidth;
  this.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;
  this.drawableResourceCollection = drawableResourceCollection;
  this.animationSpeedInFpms = animationSpeedInFps / 1000.0;
  this.startTimeInMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  this.animationForward = animationForward;
}

public double getxPosition()
{
  return xPosition;
}

public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
  drawableResourceCollection.get(currentFrame).setBounds((int) xPosition, (int) yPosition, (int) xPosition + getWidth(), (int) yPosition + getHeight());
  drawableResourceCollection.get(currentFrame).draw(canvas);
  currentFrame = 1;
}



public void canvasChanges(int canvasWidth, int canvasHeight)
{
  this.canvasWidth = canvasWidth;
  this.canvasHeight = canvasHeight;
}

public void setxPosition(int xPosition)
{
  this.xPosition = xPosition;
}

public double getyPosition()
{
  return yPosition;
}

public void setyPosition(int yPosition)
{
  this.yPosition = yPosition;
}

public void reverseAnimation()
{
  animationForward = !animationForward;
}

public int getWidth()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

   }
  return drawableResourceCollection.get(currentFrame).getIntrinsicWidth();
}

public int getHeight()
{
  return drawableResourceCollection.get(currentFrame).getIntrinsicHeight();
}

public void Move(double frameTime)
{
  double newXPosition = velocity.getNewXPosition(xPosition, frameTime);
  if (newXPosition + getWidth() < (canvasWidth - 4) && newXPosition > 4)
     xPosition = newXPosition;

  yPosition = velocity.getNewYPosition(yPosition, frameTime);
}

public boolean CollidesWith(Sprite sprite, double frameTime)
{
  int left1, left2;
  int right1, right2;
  int top1, top2;
  int bottom1, bottom2;

  left1 = (int) this.getNewXPosition(frameTime);
  left2 = (int) sprite.getNewXPosition(frameTime);
  right1 = left1 + this.getWidth();
  right2 = left2 + sprite.getWidth();
  top1 = (int) this.getNewYPosition(frameTime);
  top2 = (int) sprite.getNewYPosition(frameTime);
  bottom1 = top1 + this.getHeight();
  bottom2 = top2 + sprite.getHeight();

  if (bottom1 < top2)
     return false;
  if (top1 > bottom2)
     return false;
  if (right1 < left2)
     return false;
  if (left1 > right2)
     return false;

  int over_bottom;
  int over_top;
  int over_right;
  int over_left;

  if (bottom1 > bottom2)
     over_bottom = bottom2;
  else
     over_bottom = bottom1;

  if (top1 < top2)
     over_top = top2;
  else
     over_top = top1;

  if (right1 > right2)
     over_right = right2;
  else
     over_right = right1;

  if (left1 < left2)
     over_left = left2;
  else
     over_left = left1;

  for (int xPos = over_left; xPos < over_right; xPos++)
  {
     for (int yPos = over_top; yPos < over_bottom; yPos++)
     {
        int thisColor = this.getPixel(xPos, yPos);
        int spriteColor = sprite.getPixel(xPos, yPos);
        if (thisColor != 0 && spriteColor != 0)
        {
           return true;
        }
     }
  }

  return false;
}

public double getNewXPosition(double frameTime)
{
  return velocity.getNewXPosition(xPosition, frameTime);
}

public double getNewYPosition(double frameTime)
{
  return velocity.getNewYPosition(yPosition, frameTime);
}

private int getPixel(int x, int y)
{
  int xPosInBitmap;
  if (x > getxPosition())
     xPosInBitmap = x - (int) getxPosition();
  else
     xPosInBitmap = (int) getxPosition() - x;

  int yPosInBitmap;
  if (y > getyPosition())
     yPosInBitmap = y - (int) getyPosition();
  else
     yPosInBitmap = (int) getyPosition() - y;

  if (x >= internalBitmap.getWidth() || y >= internalBitmap.getHeight())
     return 1;

  if (yPosInBitmap < this.internalBitmap.getHeight() && xPosInBitmap < internalBitmap.getWidth())
     return this.internalBitmap.getPixel(xPosInBitmap, yPosInBitmap);
  else
     return 0;
}

public void center()
{
  centerHorizontal();
  centerVertical();
}

public void centerHorizontal()
{
  setxPosition(canvasWidth / 2 - getWidth() / 2);
}

 public void centerVertical()
 {
  setyPosition(canvasHeight / 2 - getHeight() / 2);
 }

 public boolean IsMaximumRight(int canvasWidth)
 {
  return getxPosition() >= (canvasWidth - getWidth());
 }

 public void SetMaximumRight(int canvasWidth)
 {
  setxPosition(canvasWidth - getWidth());
 }

 public void setVelocity(Velocity velocity)
 {
  this.velocity = velocity;
 }

 public void setPreviousLocation(double frameTime)
 {
  xPosition = velocity.getPreviousXPosition(xPosition, frameTime);
  yPosition = velocity.getPreviousYPosition(yPosition, frameTime);
 }

 public boolean IsOutOfXBounds(double frameTime)
 {
  return (getNewXPosition(frameTime) <= 7) || (getNewXPosition(frameTime) + getWidth() >=  canvasWidth - 7);
 }

 public boolean IsOutOfLowerBounds(double frameTime)
 {
  return ((int) getNewYPosition(frameTime) + getHeight() >= canvasHeight - 10);
 }

 public boolean IsOutOfUpperBounds(double frameTime)
 {
  return getNewYPosition(frameTime) <= 10;
 }
 }
```

Comment: What is `Sprite.java` line 84

Comment: @Raghunandan That is: 'return drawableResourceCollection.get(currentFrame).getIntrinsicWidth();'

Comment: Don't know whether this is a problem, but for sure in XML you do not close <FrameLayout> tag

Comment: @markubik it is closed but you are not able to see bcoz its not formatted properly. This has nothing to do with the problem

Comment: @markubik Thats weird but in the code it is. It just doesn't show up for some reason

Comment: @TheBrownCoder you din't fromat your code properly while pasting. However that line is the problem. check it

Comment: Your problem lies in your implementation of `AndrongSurfaceView`, where you are expecting some `LinkedList`(???) to have elements, when it does not. Since only you have the source code to this class and its related classes, we cannot really help you much further.

Comment: @Raghunandan I can't really see what is wrong with it But I'll look

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll add the Androng Surface View class and the drawableResourceCollection class which implements LinkedList

Comment: @TheBrownCoder Look @ at `net.semantic.games.Sprite.getWidth(Sprite.java:84)` That is where your stacktrace is pointing to.

Comment: @Raghunandan I've tried everything. I added the sprite class to my question. Its incurring the indexOutOfBounds Exception in the getWidth Method where it is trying to get the width of the image in the first (0) index. I hardcoded the 0 in to current frame yet it still doesn't work. Is it that its trying to access a drawableResourceCollection that is empty?

Comment: @TheBrownCoder the list is probably empty leading to indexoutofboudexception. good luck.

Comment: @Raghunandan ok well I'll try to see why it is turning up empty. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to the help of Raghunandan. Turns out it was never filling the drawableResourceCollection therefore it turned up empty. Please up vote his answer in the comments